# Riverpod and JustAudio

Tags: flutter, riverpod, rxdart, just-audio, flutter-streambuilder

I am currently trying to make a music player using flutter. I wanted my now playing screen and miniplayer to all have the same content and be in sync with each other throughout the entire application (the way spotify and deezer do it).
I'm still a newbie and have some basics of riverpod and just audio packages.
I think it has something to do with state management but still don't know where to start from.

I previously created an audio player using just audio though the UI was mixed with the Audioplayer object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can research this simple project as combination of riverpod and just_audio:
https://github.com/IvanHerreraCasas/music_app